# selectively disabling elements from an array of controls with one CanExecute

Tags: c#, wpf

I have an WPF interface where I have many (over 40) buttons that perform similar tasks that were parameterized by button name, that I had linked to one Command. In my command handler I had tools to determine which of the 40 buttons had been clicked. The question was how can you selectively disable or enable some of these commands based on runtime conditions. There is concern that having one CanExecute method that would be applied to different components and differentiate based on e.Source identity would not work.

Comment: What exactly is not working, does `e.Source` not contain the right button or is the `CanExecute` method not called?

Comment: @bitbonk I am having difficulties reproducing the problem, so I will try to close this question. I think there is no problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tests show that this is achievable using a CanExecute method constructed in the following way:

```
private void MyCommandCanExecute(object sender, CanExecuteRoutedEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Source == button1)
        e.CanExecute = checkBox1.IsChecked.HasValue ? checkBox1.IsChecked.Value : false;
    if (e.Source == button2)
        e.CanExecute = checkBox2.IsChecked.HasValue ? checkBox2.IsChecked.Value : false;
    if (e.Source == button3)
        e.CanExecute = checkBox3.IsChecked.HasValue ? checkBox3.IsChecked.Value : false;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't see any reason to bind all buttons to the same command, if execute logic is different.

I would really like to see commands separate, than a big if else block with all button names

Comment: My concern is that writing 40 if statements is shorter and easier to read and maintain than 40 separate methods that have a CanExecute signature.

Comment: Are the buttons doing different stuff? would you write if block for every button?

Comment: yes, the buttons are static and do practically the same thing, send a message to a server containing a different byte. Maybe not your everyday user scenario. I agree if these buttons were doing completely different things (and had a lot of logic moreover) having separate commands would be desirable.

Comment: I could do that, but in this case it wouldn't let me save any typing. Each "button" still has a unique identity.